# How to handle data upload during offline or poor network connection in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am working on a a POS App which constantly generates transactions that need to be uploaded into the server immediately. But there is a situation where Internet connection is not available all the time for certain hours and even for certain days. In this situation app goes stall while constantly trying to upload data and checking internet connection. How can I handle this situation so that app behaves normally even there is no Internet connection for 30 days.

Comment: use local DB to store data, if internet is not available.Once you get connectivity synch data to server

Comment: Hello... thanks for the reply. I am using the local DB to store the data but during syncing i have to check the active internet connection. The iPad is connected to a router (WiFi) but sometimes the router does not have the active internet connection. In this situation "currentReachabilityStatus" of the "Reachability" class returns "ReachableViaWiFi" status, and so the device assumes there is internet connection. It constantly tries to sync the data but fails. So how can we check the actual internet connection?